# Parent Case field not showing on the Case Highlights Panel

Tags: service-cloud-console, case-object, compact-layout, highlights-panel

I added the standard field 'Parent Case' to the Compact Case Layout but I dont see it on the Highlights Panel. I am sure I am pointing to the right Layout, because I can see the other fields been added or removed.

I checked the Field Level Security, and the Parent Case is visible by all profiles.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the compact Layout always 1st field not visible in the `highlighted panel`

See the below example:
[image]

Record detail Page:
[image]
[image]

In your case change the field order in compact layout then you can able to see the parent case field in the highlighted panel.

Comment: Thanks @Ankaiah Bandi, it is very weird how this works, but it solved my issue.